# How to format store hours?

Tags: swift, textview, format, display

I'm trying to display store hours.  For example, in text file, it is being saved as: Mon Tue 9am-4pm Wed-Thur appointment only

In Swift, for my textView, how do I format it such that it will display with new lines?

Mon-Tue 9am-4pm  (new line)
Wed-Thur appointment only

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if MasterViewController.MyVariables.companyImage != nil {
        imageView1.image = MasterViewController.MyVariables.companyImage!

        hoursText2.text = MasterViewController.MyVariables.hours

    }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   configureView()
```

}

Comment: Insert a line feed where you want the lines to break.

Comment: Hi Ken, do u mean to put \n on the text file?  I tried it but this doesn't work.

Comment: I can't tell what you tried or didn't try, because it's not in your post. All I can see is `hoursText2.text = MasterViewController.MyVariables.hours`, not what `hours`  contains or what `hoursText2.text` actually holds after the assignment.

Comment: Hi Ken, it actually holds this value: Mon Tue 9am-4pm Wed-Thur appointment only

Comment: It is displaying in the textbox as such.  Just wondering how do I tell Swift to put a new line after Mon-Tue time

Comment: Yes, you say that in your post (or did before you added *(new line)* in your last edit. That doesn't really explain anything. I can look at a file that contains `abc        xyz` and not see that it contains a tab character and not spaces.